# How do I create flexible div containers that marry float behavior with dynamic widths and heights?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create the below situation where the `content_container`'s width reaches the right side of the screen and automatically scales depending on whether the expandable pane is collapsed or not. If I put `width: 100%` on `.content_container` it goes past the width of the screen, creating an unnecessary scroll bar as well as shifts to being under the expandable pane. Also you can see that the `expandable_pane`'s height does not reach the full extent of the parent, but the `content_container`'s does.

There is obviously something I'm not understanding on a fundamental level as I will admit that my grasp of various display types and behaviors is not solid and I'm still learning. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expandable_pane").click(function(){
    if(this.className.search("collapsed") != -1){
        this.className = this.className.replace("collapsed", "extended");
    } else {
        this.className = this.className.replace("extended", "collapsed");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.expandable_pane{
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(98,98,98);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.expandable_pane.collapsed {
  width: 10px;
}

.expandable_pane.extended {
  width: 500px;
}

.flex_container {
  height: 300px;
}

.content_container{
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content_pane {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(98,98,98);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="expandable_pane collapsed" id="expandable_pane">
    Menu Icons/Links would go here.
  </div>
  <div class="content_container">
    <div class="content_pane">
      Information for page here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't that far off with your code. First of all, your `.flex_container` class is missing `display: flex`. Secondly, if you want your container to take up the remainder of the space, it needs to be able to flex. If you give the container `flex: 1 100px`, which is a shorthand property, it tells the container to `flex-grow: 1` with a flex-basis of `100px`. With flexbox, you no longer need `float: left` in this scenario.

Try playing around with the values to get a better grasp of how flexbox can work and I also recommend reading the MDN articles on the property. [MDN Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expandable_pane").click(function(){
    if(this.className.search("collapsed") != -1){
        this.className = this.className.replace("collapsed", "extended");
    } else {
        this.className = this.className.replace("extended", "collapsed");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.expandable_pane{
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(98,98,98);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.expandable_pane.collapsed {
  width: 10px;
}

.expandable_pane.extended {
  width: 500px;
}

.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.content_container{
  padding-left: 10px;
  flex: 1 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content_pane {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(98,98,98);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="expandable_pane collapsed" id="expandable_pane">
    Menu Icons/Links would go here.
  </div>
  <div class="content_container">
    <div class="content_pane">
      Information for page here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, @loomy. I might also suggest OP make the default CSS width for .expandable_pane the same as it is when it has the .collapsed class applied (width: 10px;). After that the jQuery could use the .toggleClass('extended') method instead, just to keep the code a tdd bit cleaner. Either way,  on this flexbox implementation.

Comment: This worked so thanks a million! This is my first time working with flexbox code so I'm still trying to grasp the nuances and I love how clean it can make things look, so again thanks so much. And to TristanZimmerman, yeah! That's an excellent suggestion!